# Group similar records in a list by maintaining order and relevancy

Tags: c#, linq

I am rephrasing the question with more clear sample data to help the members better understand my problem.

I have used linq for fairly basic queries but have no idea how to write complex queries. I have data like this in a list,

```
var list = new List<Users>()
{ 
  new Users() { FirstName = "John", LastName= "Doe", MiddleName = "P.", Phone = "111-111-111", Email = "abc@xyz.com" },      
  new Users() { FirstName = "Alex", LastName= "Jones", MiddleName = "S", Phone = "333-333-222", Email = "xyz@abc.com" },   
  new Users() { FirstName = "John", LastName= "Doe", MiddleName = "p.", Phone = "111-111-111", Email = "abc@xyz.com" },   
  new Users() { FirstName = "John", LastName= "Doe", MiddleName = "", Phone = "111-222-111", Email = "abc@xyz.com" },   
  new Users() { FirstName = "John", LastName= "", MiddleName = "", Phone = "111-111-111", Email = "abc@xyz.com" },   
  new Users() { FirstName = "Alex", LastName= "James", MiddleName = "N", Phone = "111-111-111", Email = "cde@xyf.com" },   
  new Users() { FirstName = "Alex", LastName= "Jones", MiddleName = "S", Phone = "333-333-222", Email = "xyz@abc.com" },   
  new Users() { FirstName = "John", LastName= "Doe", MiddleName = "", Phone = "111-222-111", Email = "" }, 
};
```

These are just sample records for a user and there are thousands of records like this. I want to sort/group the users such that for a single user (FirstName, LastName) the top most records will be those which FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, Phone and Email match. After these those records needs to come whose FirstName, LastName, MiddleName and Phone are matching. So rows with most matching columns will be on top and rows with least matching columns will be on bottom. Rows of a single user should not overlap with other users so similar user's records will be together.

What I have tried:

I have used the following Linq query to achieve the desired results,

```
obj = obj.OrderBy(x => (chkFirstName.Checked) ? x.FIRSTNAME : "")
                               .ThenBy(x => (chkLastName.Checked) ? x.LASTNAME : "")
                               .ThenBy(x => (chkMiddleName.Checked) ? x.MIDDLENAME : "")
                               .ThenBy(x => (chkPhone.Checked) ? x.PHONE_PRIMARY : "")
                               .ThenBy(x => (chkEmail.Checked) ? x.EMAIL1 : "").ToList();
```

It is not getting me the order correctly. For example this query will group most matching columns rows on top for a user then few records will be for another user. I am thinking that may be Group can do this? Kindly guide me through this.

(Note): There are extra columns in the List which I have not mentioned but they will not be used for any sorting or grouping.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Does the duplicate-count matter for the order, so that items with most duplicates are at the top?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Yes the count matters. You are right the most duplicates will be on top.

Comment: @AdnanYaseen: so not only the duplicate-property-count but also the duplicate-group-count matters, what has highest priority? Is it simplified so that you actually want an approach which also works if there are 10 properties or more?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter The basic idea to is to group on all coulmns (any number). Duplicate property has the highest priority then the duplicate group. I am going to provide filter options to the user. So by dfeault it is group on all columns (here in this case 3) and it can be less.

Answer (score 0):

You can do order by

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(l => l.FirstName).ThenBy(l => l.LastName).ThenBy(l => l.MiddleName).ToList();
```

Comment: Does not take care of the duplicate-column-count or the size of the duplicate-groups.

Comment: @huMpty duMpty its perfect if duplicate-column-count is not required. +1 for answering promptly.

Comment: @AdnanYaseen: it's perfect for a different requirement. No offense

Comment: @AdnanYaseen it results exactly what you shown in Q as `Expected Output`. Probably you should expand the `Expected Output`

Comment: @Javad_Amiry I agree that it relates to expected output but as I mentioned that most matches on the top and least matches on bottom and it was understood by Tim Schmelter and he asked me if this is what I want?

Comment: @AdnanYaseen: Can you please provide example where duplication occurs?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = list.OrderBy(t => t.FirstName).ThenBy(t => t.LastName).ThenBy(t => t.MiddleName);
```

Comment: Does not take care of the duplicate-column-count or the size of the duplicate-groups.